# Android Send User Latitude And Longitude On Xmpp Server Using ASmack

Tags: android, xmpp, android-maps-v2, asmack

**I am new in android and xmpp. 
I am fully setup my xmpp server with asmack library in android.
My aim is i want to send user latlng to server and track  user on server side map (with php).
Now i am sending latlng throw message ( using asmack ) to server.But i think its not good way.
So friends please tell me right way how to do that. 
Sorry for my bad english.
Thankx in advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible, that depends on what you want. If only tracing coordinates without creating a path with all points, you can use something simple, may be udp or http... But if you want to accumulate all data, that's needed something like queues support...